# How to define JSS component in YAML without DataSource Template

Tags: jss

I need to define a component in YAML manifest files in Sitecore JSS CodeFirst approach, where component doesn't have any "Data Source Template" field populated.

In this case, NO template should be created for this component in template section also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done by defining a component in the manifest that has no fields, for example:

### Without Datasource

```
import { addComponent } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-manifest';

export default (manifest) => {
  addComponent(manifest, {
    name: 'Welcome',
  });
};
```

### With Datasource

```
import { addComponent, CommonFieldTypes } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-manifest';

export default (manifest) => {
  addComponent(manifest, {
    name: 'Welcome',
    fields: [{ name: 'title', type: CommonFieldTypes.SingleLineText }],
  });
};
```